# Set SQL Server 'Maximum server memory in (MB)' using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I'm currently automating a VM and using a Powershell script to install SQL Server 2017.

I need to be able to script the Maximum server memory as well. Is this possible through the current configuration settings or will I need to create a custom script? If a custom script is required what would I need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use SQL (run from Powershell):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
RECONFIGURE;
```

or use PowerShell cmdlet from **[dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io/functions/set-dbamaxmemory/)**:

> **Set-DbaMaxMemory**
>
> explicitly set the max memory to 2048 MB on just one server, “sqlserver1”
>
> ```
> Set-DbaMaxMemory -SqlServer sqlserver1 -MaxMb 2048
> ```

Answer (score 2):

By using [sqlps module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sql-server-powershell) it's possible to address this task the next way:

```
Import-Module Sqlps
$sql16 = ls 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\(local)'|? InstanceName -eq 'SQL16'
$sql16.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.RunValue
$sql16.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.ConfigValue = [Math]::Floor($sql16.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.RunValue * 1.5)
$sql16.Alter()
$sql16.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.RunValue
```